# Is there an extra character on the first readline() of a file?

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, utf-8, byte-order-mark

The first line of a file I'm reading in seems to obey different rules than the rest of the lines.

Expected behavior: Each line checks for a hash at the beginning and if it doesn't find one, then it does actions.

Actual behavior: That's true except for the first line. The first line somehow gets through to a try/except in checkForMatch().

Hack: If I include a second readline to get past the first one, all subsequent lines work fine.  If I handle the try/except correctly to report and skip the first line, all subsequent lines work fine.

```
rulesFile = open("example.tsv","r",encoding="utf-8")

# line = rulesFile.readline()
line = rulesFile.readline()
while line != "":
    line = line.lstrip()
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line != "" and line[0] != "#":
        checkForMatch(line, args)
    line = rulesFile.readline()
```

The first and second lines both consist of hash, space, ascii text.

```
# First line
# Second line
```

I looked at some other answers and tried replacing

```
line[0] != "#"
```

with

```
not line.startswith("#")
```

It may be more pythonic, but the output remains identical.

Is there a secret initial character on the first line of a file, or some other subtle problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot about the BOM.

```
rulesFile = open("example.tsv", "r", encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

Comment: Forget, not at all. Had never seen the encoding notation and trusted someone else's old script... Does -sig work for all bit orders or are there different encoding values I might have to try?

Comment: UTF-8 only has a single byte order.

Comment: I'm dropping the link to more information (and arguments) about BOM and UTF-8, because I was trying to figure out why both utf-8 and utf-8-sig existed. If you're wondering that too, here you go.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom